# How can i send two parameters using ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

i am trying two send two values to new page i am new to jquery how can i concatinate them:

> The Error is in location line   ('')

here my ajax code:

```
success: function (response) {
if(response["success"]==true)
{
    $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
    location = '/learningcurve/gdpi.php?jobid=='+response["id"]'&jobname=='+response["jobname"];
     window.open(location);
```

[image]

Comment: replace `==` with `=`

Comment: Not working... wait let me add image of my error

Comment: try with this :- `"/learningcurve/gdpi.php?jobid="+response['id']+"&jobname="+response['jobname'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
success: function (response) {
if(response["success"]==true)
{
    $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
    location = "/learningcurve/gdpi.php?jobid="+response["id"]+"&jobname="+response["jobname"];
     window.open(location);
```

Comment: It Worked like magic thank you. i cant vote i dont have 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to concatenate:

```
'+response["id"]+'
```

Notice the `+`.